# Remove padding from Kendo react dropdownButton

Tags: reactjs, kendo-ui, kendo-react-ui

I have a DropDownButton

```
<DropDownButton text="i" items={items}  />
```

that has padding around it

[image]

How would one remove that padding for **just this one button not all of them on the site** ?

See for more context

https://codesandbox.io/s/unruffled-snow-cx50hi

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can also pass `buttonClass` prop to that particular `DropDownButton`, I have also shown it here.
https://codesandbox.io/s/crazy-forest-1lvs7f?file=/app/main.tsx

Please check the props that are being passed to DropDownButton for a better understanding.

Answer (score 1):

Add below css in a new file called `style.css`

```
button {
  padding: 0 !important;
}
```

and import it in main.tsx as
`import ./style.css`

Comment: Yes that would do it globally to all buttons what if I want to do it to just this one ?